# Visual Studio Command Line PATH different than cmd PATH?

Tags: python, c++, cmd, cmake

I am building a project which requires the visual studio command line rather than cmd. It requires python and cmake, which when I use cmd are available.

However, when I use the visual studio command line and type 'python' or 'cmake', it does not recognize these variables.

Any help on how to add these environment variables to my visual studio command line??

Comment: Are you launching vsvars32.bat via cmd ?

Comment: Yes. And I just tried the project on another computer, and it actually worked, however it fails on mine. Will close the question and move on to the next one, but thank you none the less :)